# Guest OS login prompt is overriding host OS login when using VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, login

I am using VirtualBox in my host running Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Ubuntu 14.04 as a guest OS. After leaving the host idle for a while, I see login prompt of 16.04, but when I click on the screen(without entering password), it redirects me directly to the guest OS login prompt.

Comment: You're running the guest OS full screen?

Comment: Not full screen. guest os runs in a window.

Comment: Then the guest OS has locked? This is standard. Ubuntu doesn't care that's it a VM, you have to tell it to not lock the screen.

Comment: Yeah. Both os'es are locked but the problem is that the guest os login is prompted to me first than otherway around.

Comment: So you're saying that the VM window is appearing on top of the host's lock screen? This would be a serious (local) security issue. Can you provide a screenshot/photo showing this?

Comment: No. Host's lock screen appears, but just when i click on it, it disappears and takes me to guest os login screen.